# CSS overlapping text when resizing browser

Tags: css, overflow, overlapping

I'm trying to copy (just as exercise in CSS) [this website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8txdL.png). In full size browser it looks fine (my [overall result](https://i.imgsafe.org/88efee85df.png)), but when resizing I get two problems:

1) Menu is overlapping with the name "Pico" (like [here](https://i.imgsafe.org/88effc9eec.png) and [here](https://i.imgsafe.org/88f0091485.png)).

2) One of the div doesn't fill the browser in all its width ([here](https://i.imgsafe.org/88efda95ed.png)).

I've tried to play `width: 100%` and `overflow` values, but couldn't figure out the problem.

Here's the code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrht6wrt/).

Comment: 1: Because of absolute position, adding `margin-left: 150px;` to the `.menu` will demonstrate its principle ...2: In the fiddle the div fill width, so you need to tell which one and when

Comment: Better if you try this with Bootstrap(http://getbootstrap.com/) It will be easier to manage without doing many things on your own.

Comment: @LGSon, Thanks for the first point, it works well. For the second question: Narrow down the width of the website display in fiddle until the scroll bar appears at the bottom, then just go on the right with the scroll and down until `div level` (white background). There's dark background "peeking out" from behind white one, like [here](https://i.imgsafe.org/89c67dfdb9.png).

Comment: SOLVED, seems the culprit was 'min-width' in .header. Thanks again for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because `.menu` class has `position: absolute` and don't see 'Pico' text.
2. Remove min-width from `.header` and add `flex-wrap: wrap` to `.level`.

Comment: Well, removing 'min-width' seems to do the trick. The 'flax-wrap' however change the structure of the website, making the icons nested instead of "gridded". Anyhow, the problem solved. Thanks!